# how to resolve ip to hostname history records on premise network?

Tags: dns, active-directory, ip, hostname, dhcp

How can i get mapping of an ip address to a hostname history records on premise network?

i wish to get something like this data:

```
192.168.1.1 was maped to: mycomp.mydomain.dom from: 1/1/2016 to: 1/2/2016
192.168.1.2 was maped to: mycomp.mydomain.dom from: 1/2/2016 to: 1/3/2016
192.168.1.1 was maped to: othercomp.mydomain.dom from: 1/1/2016 to: 1/2/2016
etc...
```

for all domain records.
is there an option to query the enterprise dns server? or maybe Active directory?

Comment: Do you want a list of the actual records or an audit of queries made? Do you want this retrospectively or how to enable that going forward?

Comment: a list of actual records, and retrospective records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DNS servers support `axfr` queries, which are Zone transfers. which will basically give you a dump of the entire domain. You could script that to create that dump on a schedule.

In order to allow Zone Transfers you need to enable the server to do so.

On Bind servers you need to add

```
acl trusted-servers  {
        192.168.191.10;  //ns2
        25.111.24.6;   //ns3
};
```

To the zone.

For Windows you can run this command (as discussed on technet article [Modify DNS zone transfer settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782181(v=ws.10).aspx)

```
dnscmd ServerName /ZoneResetSecondaries ZoneName /SecureList[SecondaryIPAddress...]
```

As for discovering those records retrospectively, the best bet you've got for that is going through backups, for bind there will be Zone files. For AD it depends how it is set up, but they *should* be stored  as .dns files in the %SystemRoot%\System32\Dns folder on the primary and secondary nameservers.

Comment: can i export all dns records to .csv/other file format using axfr? is there another way to get history of IP addresses for a hostname through some kind of api?

Comment: Simply, no! axfr is a DNS request that has a specific format, there is more about it [here](https://digi.ninja/projects/zonetransferme.php) - the only way to get an historical record would be to go through your backups. There's no API to do that.